# Address Book in an Popover

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller, abpeoplepickerview

Does anyone have an example of tell me how I might open up the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController inside a popover.  I have the NavigationController that is being used in the popover doing the opening, but it opens up full screen/modal.

Am I missing something here or will I need to write my own people picker to show it in the popover?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your `UIPopoverController`, then add an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`.

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *contacts = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:contacts];
```

Comment: Where do I put the delegate methods for this?  I have them in the Nav controller where this is being shown.  Is that the correct spot, because they aren't getting called?

Comment: I was missing [picker setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];